# How to return instance of a class from its static attribute in python

Tags: python

Just curious, 
Is it possible to keep static attrs in a class that returns instantiated objects for the same class? Specifically not using a factory method but attr

```
class Money:
    CENT = Money('cent')

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

Money.CENT    #==> Returns Money('cent')
```

The best I could come up with is, But not within the same class.

```
class SampleMoney:
    CENT = Money('cent')
    DOLLAR = Something('dollar')

SampleMoney.CENT #==> Money('cent')
```

Comment: Does it need to be an attr or can it be a method?

Comment: Why would you want to do that, I am sure there is a better way to serve your use case.

Comment: attr, With method it is easy to return a new instance

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. Using a method is the factory pattern

Comment: Just put `Something.EMPTY = Something('empty')` after the class definiton.

Comment: @DietrichEpp how will it be used? This cannot be imported

Comment: What do you mean "this cannot be imported"?  All you are doing is moving a line of code from inside the class definition to outside the class definition.  It doesn't change how you use the code, it doesn't change how imports work.

Comment: Oh yeah got it, Sorry It was my IDE complaining about it. But it works Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following hack to create a class property:

```
class Something:
    class __metaclass__:
        @property
        def EMPTY(cls):
            return cls('empty')
```

Alternatively, just define it after?

```
class Something:
    # ...

Something.EMPTY = Something('empty')
```